# how to use one managed bean for tow methods and save the data in variables?

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I have tow command in one page that use one managed bean. first method creates a Tour and second one adds photo urls to that tour. but the problem is that when i call the second method the tour i created is lost and returns null. how can i solve this?

```
@ManagedBean(name="addtour")
@SessionScoped
public class CreateTourAction {
private Tour tour;
public String execute() {
    tour = new Tour(this.date,this.province,this.country, this.category,transportation,this.gregarious,this.days, this.space,BigDecimal.valueOf(price));

    tour.save();
    return"success";
}
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {  
    tour.setImg_urls(urls);
    tour.save();
}
```

xtml related part:

```
<h:commandButton value="Create" action="#{addTour.execute}"/>

<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{addTour.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="true"  
              update="messages" sizeLimit="1000000" fileLimit="3" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />
```

Comment: So `tour.setImg_urls(urls);` will throw a `NullPointerException`? The code looks okay so far, try to debug and find out whether the bean is still the same for both requests. The bean should also be `Serializable`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` keyword. It is a reference to the current object. But if this current object is not initialized before call one of setter method, you get `NullPointerException`. So, I offer to inicializate `tour` object in constructor or always call first the `execute()` method. I modified your code, but I don't initialize tour, because it is your decission:

```
@ManagedBean(name="addtour")
@SessionScoped
public class CreateTourAction {
private Tour tour;
public String execute() {
    this.tour = new Tour(this.date,this.province,this.country, this.category,transportation,this.gregarious,this.days, this.space,BigDecimal.valueOf(price));

    this.tour.save();
    return"success";
}
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
if(this.tour != null){  
    this.tour.setImg_urls(urls);
    this.tour.save();
}
}
```

I hope this code helpfull for you!

Comment: Yes I know. In your case when first call `handleFileUpload` this `tour` is `null`. Of course `this` not solved your problem, but I described in my answer you need initialize in constructor or field: `private Tour tour;` change to `private Tour tour = new Tour();`